# Where was the Barberini psalter created?

Tags: middle-ages, christianity, italy, book, origins

Would you know where the [Barberini psalter](https://www.doaks.org/resources/mmdb/manuscripts/vatican-city-biblioteca-apostolica-vaticana-barb-gr-372) was created?

I have checked the on-line sources and cannot find the answer (maybe I have overlooked it?)

It was created in the 11th century. The obvious answer would be "Florence, because [Barberinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barberini_family) lived in Florence in the 11th century", but I am not sure because the objects can be named after their later owners, not after those who have commissioned them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I know. It was not created in Florence but in the [Monastery of Saint John the Forerunner "at Stoudios"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastery_of_Stoudios).

Comment: My understanding is that recent scholarship argues that it was created in the scriptorium of the Stoudios monastery in Constantinople.  See for example [Perceptions of Byzantium and Its Neighbors: 843-1261](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WUAa72T7DZUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) p24.